# Change the colour of text field in dynamics crm 2016

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am looking to write a javascript to change the color of any text field in CRM
Here is my javascript:

```
function ChangeBackgroundColor()
{
     var revenue = window.parent.Xrm.Page.getAttribute("revenue").getValue();
     if(revenue < 10000)
     {
          document.getElementById("websiteurl").style.backgroundColor = "Red";

     }
}
```

It is throwing me an error saying "Cannot read property 'style' of null at ChangeBackgroundColor "

Can i get this customization done ? If yes then how? If no then why ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no supported way of changing background color of fields in CRM. I recommend you find an alternative solution, such as setting notifications on the form or field: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_setnotification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in Dynamics CRM 2016 but you will need to modify the setting 'Use Legacy Form Rendering' to 'Yes'. Go to **Settings - Administration - System Settings** then on the tab **'General'** there is the setting 'Use Legacy Form Rendering'

[image]

Then your code will work.

I would like to remind you that this is indeed unsupported and that it can be that it does not work anymore in future updates.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do this customization, because it's not a supported customization for Dynamics CRM

Comment: SO it is not possible in any case ??

Comment: it's not a supported customization, personally I avoid unsupported customizations

Comment: It is possible but only when you use legacy form rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, it is not possible. But as @YacineZine mentioned, you can use *"Legacy Form Rendering"* as a substitute, but then it affects performance(also mentioned before the radio button).
But as we all know CRM does have some restrictions, so in next update or upgrade, your customization might not be supported.
So it is always wise to avoid such kind of customization.

Answer (score 0):

Put the attribute in an html form embedded in an iFrame, and put the iFrame onto the form; then you can do whatever you want with the field.  But Guido is right, this customization is not supported on standard CRM forms (very few, if any, "style" customizations are supported in CRM).